# Start services killed using killall

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, redhat

Recently I was working on an update and I had to kill a few java process before that.

```
killall -9 java
```

So I used the above command which killed all the java process. But now I'm stuck without knowing how to restart those java services.

Is there a command to start all java services killed using killall?

Answer (score 2):

## using kill

First of all: kill -9 should be the last method to use to stop a process.

A process stopped with SIGKILL has no chance to shutdown properly. Some services or daemons have complex and important shutdown procedures like databases who takes care to close open database files in a consistent state and write cached data to it.

Before stopping processes with kill or something like that, you should try the stop procedure which comes from the init system of your unix/linux operating system.

When you have to use *kill*, try to send a TERM signal to a process first (just use kill without -9) and wait a moment to see if the process shuts down. Use -9 if there is no other option!

## Starting and stopping services

Starting and stopping services should be handled by the init service which comes with your unix/linux operating system.

*SysV init* or *systemd* is common. Check the Manual of your operating system to see which system is used. If set up properply you can check which services are missing (stopped, which should be running) and start them again.

here are some manual examples

FreeBSD:
https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/configtuning-rcd.html

Debian:
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/unix-services.de.html#sect.system-boot

Fedora: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f28/system-administrators-guide/infrastructure-services/Services_and_Daemons.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. There is no record (by default) of what you have killed, as you can see in `strace killall java`.

[More about process management](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement), including why SIGKILL is a bad idea almost all of the time.